# Ruby on Rails: find elements with value inside of a collection's array

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a `Domain` model with an `ips` attribute that holds ip addresses:

```
=> #<Domain:0x005640cef7cd48> {
              :id => 1,
            :name => "example.com",
             :ips => [
        [0] #<IPAddr: IPv4:1.2.3.4/255.255.255.255>
    ]
}
```

And I want to find all domains which have the same ip address. So something like:

```
Domain.where(|d| d.ips.include? "1.2.3.4")
```

Is there any straight forward way to do so?

Comment: Which database you are using?

Comment: @Pavan Postgres

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below query should work

```
Domain.where("ips @> ?", '{1.2.3.4}')
```

Or you can also do

```
Domain.where("'1.2.3.4' = ANY (ips)")
```

[*Reference*](http://blog.arkency.com/2014/10/how-to-start-using-arrays-in-rails-with-postgresql/)